# when using groupby with multiple columns, how to NOT drop an unobserved combination of columns

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a `pandas` data frame like the one below:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([[1,'A', 'First'],
                       [3,'A', 'Second'], 
                       [2,'A', 'Third'],
                       [5,'B', 'Second'], 
                       [4,'B', 'Third']])
```

Then, if I do the following:

```
df.groupby([1,2]).count()
```

the combination of `B` and `First` will be dropped because it is not in the original data frame.

**I wonder if there is a way to NOT drop this combination and instead give it a count of 0**

Comment: Minor, but "drop" seems the wrong word, given that the combination isn't there in the first place.

Comment: @DSM: That's true! I just wasn't sure how to properly explain it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to create a `MultiIndex` which contains them all and then use that to index into your counts:

```
>>> g = df.groupby([1,2]).count()
>>> g.loc[pd.MultiIndex.from_product(g.index.levels)]
           0
A First    1
  Second   1
  Third    1
B First  NaN
  Second   1
  Third    1
>>> g.loc[pd.MultiIndex.from_product(g.index.levels)].fillna(0)
          0
A First   1
  Second  1
  Third   1
B First   0
  Second  1
  Third   1
```

This works because the new MultiIndex contains the cartesian product of the levels:

```
>>> g.index
MultiIndex(levels=[['A', 'B'], ['First', 'Second', 'Third']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 1, 2]],
           names=[1, 2])
>>> pd.MultiIndex.from_product(g.index.levels)
MultiIndex(levels=[['A', 'B'], ['First', 'Second', 'Third']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]])
```